# AMQP-Client and JDK 12

Tags: java, rabbitmq, amqp-client

Has anyone used AMQP-CLIENT (RabbitMQ) with OpenJDK 12? I tried and got an SSL error when connecting with TLS1.2. It works great on JDK 8.

Comment: Which version of [`rabbitmq-java-client`](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-java-client) do you use? What error do you get?

Comment: 4.1,  but reading AMQP web-page even 5.x series says must use JDK8.

Comment: Error is an SSL error talking to RMQ server.   Works great on JDK8

Comment: No, JDK 8 is just the minimal version: "They require Java 8 **or higher**."

Comment: Yes, 8 might be minimal, but SSL with 12 fails.    When I drop to TLS1.1 it works.   I assume that a crypto-algorithm was removed.  I will try to use OPENSSL to dump the supported ones from RabbitMQ, and probably have to backward load the removed one into 12.      I might be totally off, but this is what I have found.